# Django, matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. When I run the command `python manage.py runserver` on pycharm, I get the error message like

```
2017-12-03 05:09:56,952 - INFO - server - Listening on endpoint 
tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in innerresponse = get_response(request)
File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 243, in process_exception_by_middleware
return super(AsgiHandler,self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)
File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/590/flightmate/webapp/views.py", line 180, in index airlines = RecordSet.objects.get(name="airline")
File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get self.model._meta.object_name
webapp.models.DoesNotExist: RecordSet matching query does not exist.
```

The code of `models.py` is :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import uuid
import datetime
from django.db import models

class RecordSet(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
value = models.TextField()
def __unicode__(self):
    return "{0}: {1}".format(self.name, self.value)
```

And the parent directory of `models.py` is the directory `webapp`. Any suggestions is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should add to the post the error stack in your shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the traceback, the issue is this:

```
airlines = RecordSet.objects.get(name="airline")
```

You are retrieving a single object with `get()` and since it does not exist, it returns `DoesNotExist` exception. This is also clearly mentioned in the Django documentation in the subchapter [Retrieving a single object with get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

> If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a
>   DoesNotExist exception. This exception is an attribute of the model
>   class that the query is being performed on - so in the code above, if
>   there is no Entry object with a primary key of 1, Django will raise
>   Entry.DoesNotExist.

Either use `filter()` or `get()` with `try ... except` statement. You should use `get()` if you know that there is only one object that matches your query, otherwise use `filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit late to reply to this, but For those who have similar problems, there might be other reasons that this error occurs.
This can be occurred from 'urls order or url names'

In my case, I was sending a post request through Ajax call to a url as below codes. even though I was sending the specific url for 'topic favourite' the urls.py addressed request to `topic_view` and the `topic_view` tries to match up a object with the `topic_slug` which is not given to the view function. it occurs the error `matching query does not exist.`

#### urls.py

```py
path('topic/<slug:slug>/', views.topic_view, name='topic'),
path('topic/add/', views.topic_favorite_view, name='topic_favorite'),
```

#### .js

```js
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
            topic_slug: topicSlug,
            action: 'post',
        },
        success: function (res) {
            // console.log(res)
        },
```

So what I have done is changing the url order that put the `topic_favorite` above `topic`

```py
path('topic/add/', views.topic_favorite_view, name='topic_favorite'),
path('topic/<slug:slug>/', views.topic_view, name='topic'),
```

or changed url name like this

```py
'favorite/add/'
'topic/favorite/add/'
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i fix this problem by trying this

i use `filter()` instead of `get()` so i resolve my problem. thanks for this answer

```
airlines = RecordSet.objects.filter(name="airline")
```

Answer (score -1):

Load fixtures may solve this issue
for eg python manage.py loaddata initial_data user_groups states countries permissions notification